# Splitting a string of strings in VBA

Tags: vba, string, csv, ms-word

I'm importing data into MS Word from a CSV. My issue comes when I try to split the data using the built-in split() function. It ought to be straightforward, but when I try to split it, I get a "Type mismatch" error. This is my first line of text as appears in the immediate window:

```
"Acct","SSN","Name","Last name","Phone1","Phone2","Address","City","State","Ph home","Ph work","Ph mobile","Ph other","Email","Notes","Zip"
```

When I hover over the variable during debug, however, I think the entire line is treated as a string:

```
""Acct","SSN","Name","Last name","Phone1","Phone2","Address","City","State","Ph home","Ph work","Ph mobile","Ph other","Email","Notes","Zip""
```

I'm assuming that upon import, each element of the line is treated as a string, and then the line itself is turned into one giant string? I'm really not sure. For now, all I want to do is split the line in two, and check the first item against a predetermined variable. I haven't made use of this function yet, and I'm not quite savvy with VBA on Word yet.

In short, how can I treat this line as a data type that I can interact with enough to split it into its elements? I think it's all being treated as one element, thus giving me issues.

```
    Private Function importCSV_(x)

    Dim filenum As Integer
    Dim arrLines() As String
    Dim arrSplit As Variant

    Dim textline As String
    Dim lines

filenum = FreeFile()
Open "\\...\studentData.csv" For Input As #filenum

Do Until EOF(filenum)
    Line Input #filenum, textline
    lines = lines + 1

        Debug.Print textline
        Debug.Print split(textline, ",", 2) '<--- ERROR APPEARS HERE

        arrSplit = split(textline, ",", 2)

    ReDim Preserve arrLines(lines)
        arrLines(lines) = arrSplit

    If checkForFour_(arrSplit(0)) = True Then
            arrSplit(UBound(arrLines)) = split(arrLines(lines), ",")
        Else
            arrSplit(UBound(arrLines) - 1) = split(arrLines(lines) - 1) & "," & split(arrLines(lines), ",")
        End If

Loop

Debug.Print UBound(arrLines)
Debug.Print UBound(arrSplit)

End Function
```

The checkForFour_ function is a private function that just checks the formatting of data input. I'm still learning programming and by myself for that matter, so I'm constantly making my job easier, thereby creating some garbage code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight syntax error:

```
Debug.Print split(textline, ",")(2)
```

That should do it for you. The element comes in brackets after the array.

Comment: Not quite what I was trying to do, but I can totally use this. Thanks! When I hover the variable while debugging, the item still shows up in two series of double quotes (i.e.: `""Acct""`). Any idea why it would be doing that?

Comment: It's because there are double quotes in the string when it comes in, Change `textline` to `replace(textline,"""","")` in the split and it will be fine

Comment: Oh that's so obvious. Thanks a million!